# How to trigger a jQuery function only from some elements on the page

Tags: jquery

I am trying to call a jQuery function only from specific input objects in my page. But once I set two of those objects in order to call the function, all the other elements also trigger the function. I do it this way:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        function uploadImageFile () {

            $(this).change(function (evt) {

              ..more code here    

          });
        } 


        uploadImageFile($("#FileUpload1").change); 
        uploadImageFile($("#FileUpload2").change);

        And also I tried:
        $("#FileUpload1").change(uploadImageFile());
        $("#FileUpload2").change(uploadImageFile());

 });

</script>
```

But I find other objects like ‘#FileUpload3’ or ‘#FileUpload4’ that also can trigger the function. How can I do it so that only the ojects I set can trigger the function?

Thanks

Comment: And that's an error, pretty much all of it !

Comment: No way for such a weird functionality... may be by mistake you keep the ID's same? post your html code

Comment: This selector: `$("#FileUpload1")` will identify *only* the element with an `id` of `FileUpload1`.  It won't identify other elements which have *similar* `id` values.  Something else must be wrong.  Can you post a *complete* example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: *"something else must be wrong"*, priceless, **It's all wrong**, the two first function calls doesn't pass an element, but the actual change function, and the two last calls passes undefined to the event handler, as the function is called not referenced, and then the first thing the function does, is bind the same event once more, it's just a total lack of understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to define a plugin :

```
    $.fn.uploadImageFile = function() {
        this.change(function (evt) {

          ..more code here    

       });
    } 

    $("#FileUpload1, #FileUpload2").uploadImageFile();
```

Comment: Hi,thank you. That way works fine! But I don't really know what '$.fn.uploadImageFile = function()' here does.

Comment: @CesarDev It's explained here : [Basic jQuery Plugin Creation](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).